# Upload many images to Parse

Tags: ios, json, csv, parse-platform

I'm trying to upload images to my parse class so I can use them later in my iOS App. I have over 200 images so I can't go one by one choosing file. Is there any efficient way to do it?

I've seen that I can import json and csv files. But I don't have experience on how to create those files and set the location of my images.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a file manually via Parse REST API. Take a look at this docs [here](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#files).

In order to upload your data in JSON format maybe, first the images would need to be stored in a web server, so you can access them with a URL (a JSON file only stores strings, bools, numbers... not data like an image, it might work like a reference to the server containing the image, then in your iOS app you would need to download the image from URL):

```
{ "results": [
    {
        "createdAt": "2015-07-07T15:57:07.299Z",
        "name": "Actividades Mayo",
        "objectId": "N8RI64iJO8",
        "bool": false,
        "updatedAt": "2015-08-13T17:25:03.838Z",
      here goes the image url-> "image": "https://sample.com/images/animage.jpg"
    }
]}
```

In JSON `{}` represents an object and `[]` represents an array.

And for a CSV file you would need to make a table in excel and then export it in CSV, also with a column refering to the images url. In resume you can upload them to another server OR to parse with the API.